# how to add some text in the preamble

Tags: header-footer, text

this is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a3paper,12pt,portrait]{article}
    \usepackage[Italian]{babel}  %--setta regole lingua italiana
    \usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime} %--setta data formato IT
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %--per allineamento testo a dx, sx o giustificato
    \usepackage{hyperref} %--- per i link
    \usepackage{multicol} %------ per formattare pagine a più colonne
    \usepackage{tcolorbox} %--- per le caselle di testo I pagina
    \usepackage[percent]{overpic}
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}%--posiziona testo in specifiche posizioni
    \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}%----- uso font garamond
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%----- uso font garamond
       \usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %--rimuove la linea di intestazione
  % \usepackage{showframe} %--show spazi intorno pagina
  
%--------costruisce  l'intest. ufficiale----------------------------
\fancyhead[c]{\includegraphics[width=267mm,height=39mm]{grosso_banner_corto_completo.png}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%---------------costruisce  l'intest. speciale-------------------
\fancypagestyle{special}{%
  \fancyhead[c]{\includegraphics[width=267mm,height=39mm]{grosso_banner_tutto_757per128.png}}
```

I would like to insert some text and variable (like \today)in the header (both two), when I try, I obtain an error "\begin{document} omitted” that is true! I'm still on header! How can add a line of text in the header? before to type “\begin {document}?
Thank you
Renato

Comment: You write, "if I try...". Please be more specific as to what you've tried.

Comment: As usual best would be to show a minimal working example of what you've tried.

Comment: @Mico For a new user I would absolutely agree. But not, if a user has been told the same thing again and again. And I don't see a problem in closing an unclear question, because it can be opened again, after improving the question.

Comment: sorry, I really don't understand what I need to write more. I’m asking if is it possible to write some text before the \begin{document} statement without going to compilation error.

Comment: @RenatoP → [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) BTW: You've got this link and the one to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 already before.

Comment: @RenatoP - I think that what may have some readers confused is the title of your query, "how to add some text in the preamble". Please confirm that what you actually want to achieve is "add some text to the page headers". If that's not it, please clarify your actual intent.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your code compilable, you should -- at a minimum -- (a) change `Italian` to `italian` as the argument of the `babel` package; and (b) add the option `headheight=41mm` when loading the `geometry` package, since the graphic you wish to insert in the header is 39mm deep.

A separate comment: Since your code loads the `ebgaramond-maths` math font package, shouldn't it also load the `ebgaramond` text font package -- or something reasonably equivalent?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a3paper,12pt,demo]{article}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}  %--setta regole lingua italiana
    \usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime} %--setta data formato IT
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %--per allineamento testo a dx, sx o giustificato
    \usepackage{hyperref} %--- per i link
    \usepackage{multicol} %------ per formattare pagine a più colonne
    \usepackage{tcolorbox} %--- per le caselle di testo I pagina
    \usepackage[percent]{overpic}
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}%--posiziona testo in specifiche posizioni
    \usepackage{ebgaramond}
    \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}%----- uso font garamond
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[headheight=41mm]{geometry} % <-- new option: 'headheight=41mm'. 
    
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %--rimuove la linea di intestazione
    % \usepackage{showframe} %--show spazi intorno pagina
  
    %--------costruisce  l'intest. ufficiale--------------
    \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{%
       grosso_banner_corto_completo.png}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    %---------------costruisce  l'intest. speciale---------
    \fancypagestyle{special}{%
    \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{%
       grosso_banner_tutto_757per128.png}}}
  
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want to place text (say, "Hello World") as well as a graphic in the header, I suggest you replace

```
    \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{%
       grosso_banner_corto_completo.png}}
```

with, say

```
    \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{%
       grosso_banner_corto_completo.png}%
       \par Hello World}
```

If the target height of the graphics file continues to be 39mm, you may also want to change the way you load the `geometry` package. E.g.,

```
\usepackage[top=80mm, headheight=45mm, headsep=3\baselineskip]{geometry}
```

to assure adequate amounts of whitespace both above and below the headeer material.

Comment: Thank you Mico, My question is:Can I and How insert some text in the bottom of the black box? Not after the box but inside the box

Comment: @RenatoP - Please see the addendum I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Mico Actually, `\fancyhead[c]` is OK. I always use capital letters for these parameters in the `fancyhdr` documentation for clarity, but they are case-independent.

Comment: I've substiuite with your statemen
"\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{%
       grosso_banner_corto_completo.png}%
       \par Hello World}", but Hello Word still show after the box, not inside
    \pagestyle{fancy}

Comment: @RenatoP - With the addendum code I posted, "hello world" *is* text, and it *is* within the scope of the `\fancyhd` directive. I guess I really don't understand what it is that you want to achieve. Truly sorry. Incidentally, `\pagestyle{fancy}` does *not* generate text; it just selects a certain page style.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum - Many thanks for providing this correction. I will edit my answer to incorporate this piece of information.

Comment: I don't want generate text...I would just "add some text" in the bottom of the image . text over the graphic. I could do that with graphic, but I would add also a variable (i.e \today). your example put the “hello word” in the line after the box, not over.

Comment: @RenatoP - In short, this confirms that I truly have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Should I delete my answer as it's quite apparently irrelevant and unusable?

Comment: No Mico. It is Usable! I've transformed your answer in this way:
%--------costruisce  l'intest. ufficiale--------------
     \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{%
       grosso_banner_corto_completo.png}%
       \vspace{-10mm}\par \textcolor{yellow}{Testo Testo Testo.}
}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
------------------------
and this is what I want!
I don’t know if this is the most elegant way to obtain that.
Grazie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151951/discussion-between-renatop-and-mico).